# Compact and Connected sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty compact connected sets in a Hausdorff space. I want to prove that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is nonempty, compact and connected.

If I can show that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is nonempty, then all will be proved automatically. But how it will be proved? Please give any hint.

Comment: Hint: $A_1$ is compact. If the intersection were empty, you'd get ... such that no finite ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Forget the ambient space and just work in the subpace $A_1$, which is a compact Hausdorff space. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=A_1\setminus A_n$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+$}, a non-decreasing family of open subsets of $A_1$. What can you say about $\mathscr{U}$ if $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n=\varnothing$? Then use compactness of $A_1$.